Signature of Rav Ovadia Hedaya
Rav Ovadia Hedaya ends a number of teshuvos in Yaskil Avdi with the letters וצוי״מ ומי״נ כיר׳א - what is the meaning of this abbreviation?

This is a phrase that comes from the Baal Haturim, at the end of many of his teachings. It stands for:

וצורינו יצילנו משגיאות ,ומתורתו יראינו נפלאות, כן יהי רצון אמן
May our Creator save us from errors, and from His Torah may we see wonders, may it be His will, Amen.

